# How to specify listening network interface on Kodi

Tags: kodi, remote

How can we change the network interface Kodi is listening to?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo netstat -tnlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address     Foreign Address   State    PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1183      0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN   3730/kodi.bin   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9090    0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN   3730/kodi.bin
```

I am trying to use [Kore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xbmc.kore&hl=en) to be able to control Kodi through my mobile phone. However, Kore can't find any media center on the network.
I suspect the fact that Kodi is listening on the Local loopback interface instead of eth0.

Is there a way to change it?

Comment: Kodi settings, you need to enable remote control access. When I get back I'll post an answer

Answer (score 2):

From Kodi

goto <kbd>System</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd>

[image]

goto <kbd>Services</kbd>

[image]

goto <kbd>Web Server</kbd>

[image]
And enable, set whatever credentials you want.

goto <kbd>Remote Control</kbd>

[image]

Enable both

> Allow remote control by programs on this system

and also

> Allow remote control by programs on other systems

You should now be able to use Kore to search for Media Centers on your network, connect, and control your Kodi box